# extjs6 datefield - converting to short date string

Tags: extjs, datefield

In my extjs6 project I have a datefield.  When I getvalue it comes back as '2017-07-26T00:00:00'.  How can I convert this to 07-26-2017?

I am trying the below which is coming back blank.
    var newVal = Ext.Date.format(value, 'm-d-Y')

screenshot below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs,

- [`Ext.Date.parse`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-parse) makes a javascript date from a string.
- [`Ext.Date.format`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-format) makes a string from a javascript date.

Since you need to convert a string to a string, you have to combine the two:

```
Ext.Date.format(Ext.Date.parse('2017-07-26T00:00:00','c'), 'm-d-Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use

```
Ext.Date.format and Ext.Date.parse functions
```

just change the xtype and format property to your gridcolumn

```
  xtype: 'datecolumn', 
  format: 'm-d-Y'
```

Example code set  grid column property

```
columns: [
      { 
      text: 'Date',    
      dataIndex: 'date',   
      xtype: 'datecolumn',   
      format:'m-d-Y' 
     }
  ],
```

This will give the output as in '07-26-2017' format.. 
No need to use renderer as well 
hope ull try this